# Prove the Number of Additions of Fibonacci Number Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I am studying for a final exam and I'm having trouble with this question:

The following recursive algorithm FIB takes as input an integer $n \ge 0$ and returns the $n$-th Fibonacci number $F_n$:

```
Algorithm FIB(n):

    if n = 0 or n = 1 then
        f = n
    else
        f = FIB(n-1) + FIB(n-2)
    endif
    return f
```

Let $a_n$ be the amount of additions made by the algorithm `FIB(n)`, the total number of times that the $+$-function in the else-case is called. Prove that for all $n \ge 0$

$$a_n = F_{n+1} - 1.$$

I am thinking I should use recurrence to solve it but I'm completely lost. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Computing `FIB(0)` and `FIB(1)` has no additions, as it returns `n`.

Computing `FIB(n)` has one addition, plus as many additions as `FIB(n-1)` and `FIB(n-2)` have.

So, we have

$$a_n = \begin{cases}
0, & n \in \{0, 1\}, \\
a_{n-1} + 1 + a_{n-2}, & n > 1.
\end{cases}$$

Now, use the mathematical induction to check that $a_n = F_{n+1} - 1$ and comment if you get stuck.

Comment: Am I correct with my induction? I've done it on paper and uploaded an image: http://i.imgur.com/a9ZxNt7.jpg

Comment: @pyramid No. First, you need to check $a_0$ **and** $a_1$, because recursion for $a_n$ depends on the **previous two** elements ($a_{n-2}$ **and** $a_{n-1}$). Second, for $a_{k+1}$ you go from $F_{k+1+1}$ which you want to prove, so you cannot use it. Rather, put $a_{k+1} = a_{(k+1)-1} + 1 + a_{(k+1)-2}$ (from the recurision) $= a_k + a_{k-1}$, then use the assumption on $a_k$ and $a_{k-1}$ and see that you get the result $F_{(k+1)+1}-1$.

Comment: @VedranŠego. Thank you. Can you please explain why you have "1" part in the second case of piece-wise definition? I see that number of additions for $a_4= F_{4+1}-1$, but if we calculate $F_{4+1}$ additions, we find it's 6 and not 4, so $a_4= 6-1 = 5 \ne 4$. OR you mean by  $F_{4+1}$ is the final sum and not number of additions?

Comment: @Avra, I don't follow. `a[0..4] = [0, 0, 1, 2, 4]` and `F[0..5] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`, so $a_4 = 4 = 5 - 1 = F_5 - 1$. As for the "1" in the second case: $a_{n-1}$ is the number of additions in `FIB(n-1)`, $a_{n-2}$ is the number of additions in `FIB(n-2)`, and the extra `+1` is then to add those two together.

Answer (score 0):

If we replace the "then" branch with

```
f = 1
```

then the number of additions doesn't change, because there's never any control dependency on the returned value.

However, the changed algorithm computes $F_{n+1}$ rather than $F_n$. And the way it computes $F_{n+1}$ is by adding ones, and never using an intermediate result more than once. Therefore the additions form the internal nodes in a binary tree with `1` at each leaf, so there are $F_{n+1}$ leaves. The a binary tree has one less internal nodes than it has leaves, so there must be $F_{n+1}-1$ additions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your algorithm
and turn it into
a function that computes the number of
additions done.

Algorithm nFIB(n):

```
if n = 0 or n = 1 then
    f = 0
else
    f = nFIB(n-1) + nFIB(n-2) + 1 (for the addition)
endif
return f
```

Then
$nFIB(n) = nFIB(n-1) + nFIB(n-2) + 1$
and this is pretty close to
the $F_n$ recurrence
except for that
"$+1$".

To get rid of that
(and it takes some experience
to see quickly how to do this),
change it
by adding $1$ to both sides) to get
$nFIB(n)+1 = nFIB(n-1)+1 + nFIB(n-2) + 1
$.

Therefore
$nFIB(n)+1$
satisfies the same recurrence
as $F_n$
but with possibly 
a different offset,
so
$nFIB(n)-1 = F_{n+k}$
for some $k$.
Playing around gives
$k=1$,
so
$nFIB(n) = F_{n+1}-1$.